# Any alternative to Python pickle?

Tags: python, object, ironpython, pickle

When i try to use pickle to load a dumped file, python crashes with code CLR20r3 !! I wanna know if there are any alternatives to pickle, that can dump a python object and load it back. 3rd party libraries are acceptable.

Comment: Any dumped file? Or just a particular one? What does this file contain? Give us a minimal example that reproduces the problem. Pickle is normally pretty robust, so I would be surprised if it is to blame.

Comment: If you are on windows make sure you are opening the file in binary mode

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi the dump file was created using pickle.dump itself. The dumped file is a dictionary of a lot of objects.

Comment: Be careful with pickle.  If there is any possibility of user-provided input, do not use it -- unpickling can execute arbitrary code.

Comment: @gnibbler - tried that, no use :(

Comment: @ephemient there is no user provided input in this

Comment: Are these objects pickleable? Are their subobjects pickleable as well? Show me a reproducable example.

Comment: i believe this has something to do with .net framework 4. The crash window shows invalidOperation exception is mscorlib.dll. So i was wondering if there are any other alternatives to pickle that can serialize objects. Tried marshal and json but those cant serialize objects :(

Comment: Are you using IronPython? If not, how could this be a problem with .Net? You need to provide more detail.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi yes its IronPython. I tried normal python too. Still crashes. These objects are created from data that comes from C#. Could that be the reason its its failing due to .net framework error?

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi and i am sorry i cant show you the code. Its my company code.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi the dump works fine. No errors with dumping.

Comment: I'm not asking for all the code, simply a short self-contained example that reproduces the problem. If you can't provide this, no one can help you.

Comment: http://s8.postimage.org/vik01wjz9/Untitled_picture.png

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi check the above link ! btw, you know any alternatives to pickle?

Comment: @appusajeev: The most useful suggestion you have gotten so far is to provide a simple example that can reproduce the problem. Do you have a generic method that can generate the data? Asking for alternatives is not the best solution because `pickle` is going to be the most versatile approach. Any other serializing formats will not handle as many types for you out of the box.

Answer (score 6):

I think the best answer you are going to get for the information you have provided is this...

No other serialization format is going to make your situation better. `pickle` handles native Python objects a lot more gracefully than something like JSON. Any other format will require you to define handlers to help it serialize objects it can't handle.

The best route for you is to try and solve **why** pickle is failing.